# How does below HTML code of angularJS application works and displays hidden text on web Page?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get text from a particular web element which is located in below HTML `<input>` tag. The webpage UI displaying text as "A-1", but the HTML code doesn't have text in it, since the developer used dynamic display of value selected by user from "A-1 to Z-99".

Here's the steps:
1) Double click on particular input field to set some value for it.
2) New dialog box will be open, user should be able to select values from "A-1" to "Z-99" by clicking on any value (between A-1 to Z-99).
3) Click on Save button on dialog box. Dialog box will be closed.
4) The input field should be set to user selected value "A-1" and greyed out.

The set value cannot be fetched with selenium getText() method since it is dynamically generated by AngularJS.

I would like to understand how does below HTML code of angularJS  application works and displays hidden text on web Page? So that I can use javascriptExecutor 
to fetch the value of input field.

```
<input disabled="disabled" select-on-click="" ng-disabled="!view.inEditMode" class="activity-editor ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-editable view-mode" ng-class="{ 'edit-mode': view.inEditMode, 'view-mode': !view.inEditMode, 'error': hasError, 'ng-invalid': hasError }" ng-model="selectedCode" ng-blur="actions.setCode()" name="selectActivity" maxlength="10" typeahead="code for code in autocompleteCodes | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution to get Text from dynamically generated field of angularJS application using Serenity BDD WebElementFacade interface.

Still I want to know how the hidden text is being displayed on AngularJS webpage?